# Fortnite: How to find and join a specific Creative Mode map?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

In Fortnite there was a map I was playing on for a while called *BHE 1v1 Build Fights* that was really good for practicing. Since one can easily die quickly in a build fight, and it takes maybe 20 minutes of collecting items and powering up leading up to such a showdown, a practice map is really the only way to get better.

[image: In-game screenshot of the BHE 1v1 Build Fights map]

This map was perfect for this, offering unlimited lives, ammo, and building supplies, to face off against other players building and shooting non-stop. But now I can't find it because the Creative Mode lobby area (or whatever it's called) changes frequently.

The whole navigation schema for finding a Creative Mode map is a cluster screw, since one has to fumble around a purely decorative 3D environment to navigate to a map (looks pretty, but gets annoying fast). Still, one would at least expect there to be a way to join a user-hosted map using a code or bookmark system or something. There was a code that was displayed at the top of the screen while playing: `BHE 8064-****-****` I'm not sure if it's a public code for joining, or something specific to me (hence the asterisks).

Can I use that code to look up that map or server, and join? Or is there any way of finding that awesome practice map again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all explained in [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/8iQvaQKio_w?t=63).

The thing to pay attention to is that depending on which tablet you interact with, you may be taken to a "Game Creation" menu. This is *not* what you want in this case.

Go to another one and makes sure that when you interact with it you are taken to a "Change Destination" menu. Then there will be a place to input the map code.

Answer (score 2):

go to one of the portals in creative and interact with one of the consoles next to the portals. there is a tab there called recent. go to that and you should find. if that doesn't work, search for 1v1 BHE creative codes in the internet. once you get a code, enter it in the code tab and you can play it. if you find a cool creative like this that you like, make sure to mark it as favourite so that you can easily use it any time (its like saving it).

Answer (score 0):

There is a menu with all the recent maps you played when opening a new map. It should show up there!
(Dont tell anyone, but there is a platform out there! I made an entire base using it, lol)

Comment: "when opening a new map"... I didn't see anything like a recent maps list when I went to the Hub and then Change Destination > Create New. A screenshot would be really helpful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Well.
1: You can look up on the WEB for fortnite creative codes and/or specific ones you'd like to use.
2: You can look at your recent creative maps you've played.
3: https://www.pcgamer.com/fortnite-creative-codes/     <-- you can go to this website to try and find the map your looking for.